# About network traffic control

Tags: linux, debian, routing, iptables

I have a satellite internet connection -> a pretty nice 8 processor server with 64gb of ram, running debian 7.7, two lan ports, one connected to the gateway, the other to the wifi router, wifi to all the happy devices in my home.

My problem is this, Exede only allows me so much data a month, and the devices in my home are data hogs, auto update this and that, etc.

What I am trying to do with my superior lack of knowledge is some how connect the wifi through my server to the gateway and control what devices have what kind of service, for example:

- I want my phone to be able to do whatever,
- I want the Xbox, Ps3, and my kids geexbox to connect to the server only for the purpose of connecting to minidlna but not to the web; ever, and
- I want the smart tv to connect only to netflix, minidlna and pandora but not the update server or any other web service.

What I have done so far is browsed a couple of books, mainly the linux networking cookbook, I just dont want to fill my head with this whole book and then have to sort out what is irrelevant to my cause.

I would like to be pointed in a direction of a subject that will do what I want and from there i will read up on it unless you have a nice OOTB solution. I at first considered bridging the connections in my server but that looks like it would make filtering the traffic impossible, and now I am sort of looking at an iptables solution, but then again I dont know all the options that are out there and am in severe need of pointing in the right direction.

I would also like to be able to track the total bandwidth per device to identify and correct my data hogs, and see how many of my lazy jobless friends are mooching my wifi, or see if exede is stiffing me on my data allowance which I have serious suspicions that they are.

Comment: after an hour no responses really? anywho the first part of my problem looks as if i will be building a router box with a 4 port nic to connect like;

server -> router -> gateway
wifi -> router -> gateway
HP Laserjet -> router -> LAN & gateway

and that is what i have figured out from the sections 3.14 and 3.16 of the Linux network cook book, anyone want to spare me the creation of this extra hardware?

Comment: Good grief! You come looking for help as a newbie and expect the world to fall at your feet after an hour! Maybe most people were asleep at that time, or maybe working! Chill out.

Comment: n00b, I am not, at least not in the general consensus,however new to this subject i am, but vegly, familiar with it. While some people may have been sleeping billions more were awake, and thousands of them were on here, so yeah, a pointer would have been nice, But thank you for the input either way Julian!

Answer (score 1):

In order to reduce bandwidth use of the Internet, you need to force all traffic through an intermediate that filters and caches.

A single computer can do that if it has two network cards, one connected to the inner network and the other probably goes straight to your router. The inner network should consist of a switch with the PC, printer, Wi-Fi access point on it.

So now you need to research how to turn a computer - best choose LINUX or BSD as an OS - into a filtering proxy with a firewall and routing to ensure that you are controlling traffic from each device. You should also make that device a DHCP server configured to give specific IP addresses (by MAC address) to each device connecting. That will make the firewall and routing rules much easier.

You will also need to research how to get data out of all of the various logs you will need to monitor. Take a look at references to SNMP, also check if your router and access points support SNMP and install a log server on the computer that will consolidate the logs and present a web interface.

What you are asking for is a MASSIVE job. Don't expect to get it right first or even 5th time around. But by the end, you will be quite an expert on LINUX and networking.

Good luck.

Comment: See, this is an awesome response, With that out line i can do it easy, and Linux it shall be for sure. Ill get back to ya in a couple days and see what all of this i have figured out, I bought an Intel PRO/1000 GT QUAD Port PWLA8494GTBLK D35392-006 Network Adapter, to build this new machine as soon as it gets in i should hit the ground running, hopeing it performs more like a switch than a hub but i suppose i will see there too :) I appreciate your answer!